# Qlikview Format textbox expression as percentage to 3 decimal places

Tags: textbox, expression, percentage, qlikview

I am trying to show percentage increase / decrease based on week number for 2018 v 2019 with an expression in a textbox in Qlikview: Here is my expression:

```
= num(Sum({<Year = {$(=Max(Year))}, 
Week = {"$(=Week(Today()))"}>}Retail) - Sum({<Year = {$(=Max(Year)-1)}, 
Week = {"$(=Week(Today()))"}>}Retail)) / num(Sum({<Year = {$(=Max(Year)-1)},
Week = {"$(=Week(Today()))"}>}Retail),'##0 %')
```

No matter what i try i end up with `-0.38877082` etc.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fix parenthesis and formatting:

```
= num(Sum({}Retail) - Sum({}Retail) / Sum({}Retail),'##,#0.00 %')
```

Comment: Hi Hubert, i am getting the correct calculation with this: = num(Sum({<Year = {$(=Max(Year))}>}Retail) - Sum({<Year = {$(=Max(Year)-1)}>}Retail)) / num(Sum({<Year = {$(=Max(Year)-1)}>}Retail),'##0.000%') but still not formatting to 3 decimal places.

Comment: please try ##,#0.00 %

Comment: Hi Hubert: Got it with this: '#,##0.000%' Thank You!!